# How to modify .cs files while running app locally on VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I have recently **changed from web site model to a web application model**. One change that i noticed was that in a web site, while i was running the site on  my browser locally, i could make changes to the .cs files and just refresh the browser for the changes to take effect. 
However in a web application the .cs files seem to have a lock which does not allow me to edit the .cs file without stopping the debugging.

This gets kinda lengthy since i have to stop and run again instead of making changes on the fly.

**Is there any debug setting to get around this?**

Thanks in advance.

Here is my current Edit and Continue window with the current settings. Do i need to change anything here?:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the code in a Web Application while the code is paused.  You'll need to set a break point above the line of code you wish to change.  Execute the code to reach the break point, and then while you are stopped at the break point you can modify the code.  The once the modification is done you can resume execution.

There are certain things you cannot change while paused like this, like adding in a new method.  If the change cannot be accepted while paused Visual Studio will tell, however, it won't tell you what exactly is doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is "Edit and Continue" and should be in Debug>Options and Settings>Debugging>Edit and Continue. This doesn't give you the complete flexibility to change anything you want but does allow some basic changes.

Comment: Hi, I have just edited my post with a screenshot of the edit and continue window. Can you please have a look. Also is it possible to edit .cs file on the go or not? Thanks.

Comment: @user1071979 I would try checking the bottom box. It looks correct though. What happens when you try to check it currently?

Comment: @user1071979 I had been assuming you had a break in there already. If you hadn't use the answer from JG